# CFPreferences any-host and any-application domain behavior

Tags: macos, core-foundation, cfpreferences

When using CFPreferences to set preferences on osx, there are different 
 [Preference Domains](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFPreferences/Concepts/PreferenceDomains.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001168-CJBEJBHH).

By reading the apple development guide, I understand that for **current-user**, **current-application**, **current-host** preference, it will be stored in **~/Library/Preferences/< application bundle name >.plist**. And for **any-user**, **current-application**, **current-host** preference, it will be stored in **/Library/Preferences/< application bundle name >.plist**.

But where to store preferences for other domain combinations? For example **current-user, current-application, any-host**? Will the preferences be propagated during set time (**CFPreferencesSetAppValue** follow by synchronize) to **~/Library/Preferences/< application bundle name >.plist** on all hosts that are connected to the local network and logged in as the current user? Or the magic is done during read when all hosts are consulted (but how to handle conflict preferences from different hosts in that case)?

Same question for the any-application domain, where will the preference get stored for domain such as **current-user, any-application, current-host**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "default" for preferences is current-user, current-application, any-host. Using the bundle name `com.example` for an example, these preferences would be stored at

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.example.plist
```

What makes this "any-host" is the assumption that your home directory is stored on a network share. There is no additional mechanism to synchronize it across computers. Generally speaking, you should always use any-host unless you are setting a value which really does need to be specific to the physical machine the user is sitting at.

Preferences which are set for the current host are stored under the `ByHost` directory, with a file name that includes a UUID for the computer, such as:

```
~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.example.74263C97-28D5-4AF0-8E7A-3169F1CCB545.plist
```

Preferences which are set for all applications are stored under the bundle name `.GlobalPreferences`, e.g:

```
~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist
```

and similarly for all applications, current-host:

```
~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/.GlobalPreferences.74263C97-28D5-4AF0-8E7A-3169F1CCB545.plist
```

Preferences which are set for all users follow the same pattern, except under `/Library/Preferences`.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful and complete answer. So for any-user, any-host settings, the assumption would be that the root directory needs to be stored under a network share?

Comment: @yijiem At least `/Library` would need to be shared. In practice, any-user settings are effectively local to the machine, whether they're set as current-host or not; only current-user settings are actually shared in practice.